# New object from data class .copy()

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class in Kotlin:

```
data class myDataClass(
    var a: ArrayList<Long> = ArrayList(),
    var b: ArrayList<Long> = ArrayList(),
    var c: ArrayList<Long> = ArrayList(),
    ...
)

private val myDataClassVal: myDataClass = myDataClass()
```

I use this data class to store data acquired over BLE that will, when each `ArrayList` is at a certain length, POST to a REST API. After this POST the data within `myDataClass` is `.clear()`ed and the process will repeat.

The BLE portion of the application is time sensitive and each POST is taking approximately 1 second; my solution to this is to run my POST function asynchronously; as opposed to running on the same thread as the BLE code. I do this in the following way:

```
GlobalScope.async { 
    uploadData(myDataClassVal) 
}

myDataClassVal.a.clear()
myDataClassVal.b.clear()
myDataClassVal.c.clear()
```

Unfortunately, where I am clearing the data in `myDataClass` immediately after the `async` function call the data is actually cleared from the data class before it is serialised and POSTed.

In an attempt to solve this problem I created a duplicate of `myDataClass` right before uploading and pass this into the `async` upload function. The *duplicate* is created using the `.copy()` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50237602/4816231):

```
uploadBuffer = myDataClassVal.copy()
GlobalScope.async {
    uploadData(uploadBuffer)
}
myDataClassVal.a.clear()
....
```

However, `uploadBuffer` is still completely empty. If I create a copy of `myDataClass` in the same way and POST on the same thread:

```
uploadBuffer = myDataClassVal.copy()
uploadData(uploadBuffer)
myDataClassVal.a.clear()
....
```

Then it works just fine.

So, I think my issue is that `uploadBuffer` is just a pointer to `myDataClass`. If this is the case, how do I create a new object that is a duplicate of `myDataClass` to use in my `async` POST?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: you wouldn't have these problems if you just used immutable data. And no, it's not creating a deep copy so changing on object1 will also change on the copy

Comment: @s1m0nw1 Could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, make your properties `var a: List<Long>` and don't expose the mutable version of List. This way you can make sure that once you got a list from the class it won't change afterward. instead of adding to your list you will reassign the list; instead of clearing you will reassign to an empty list etc

Comment: When a data class has several layers of object as properties the copy function creates a shallow copy with reference to children properties. Making your properties immutable looks like the best option but you can also force create deep copies of data classes. [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/deep-copy-data-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a new instance for every new run. You won't need the `copy` function, just create a new instance after launching:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    uploadData(uploadBuffer)
}
uploadBuffer = new myDataClassVal()
```

BTW: 
You should start your classes with an upper case letter, e.g. `MyDataClassVal`. See Naming Conventions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rulesan

You should use `launch` instead of `async`, because you don't need the result, see [Kotlin Async vs Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820510/kotlin-async-vs-launch/52821266#52821266)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the data only after the async task has finished, you can try using await.

```
 uploadBuffer = myDataClassVal.copy()
 GlobalScope.async {
     uploadData(uploadBuffer)
 }.await()
 myDataClassVal.a.clear() //this will execute after async returns
 ...
```

Comment: The data needs to be cleared instantly, unfortunately!

Comment: Or... maybe it doesn't, let's experiment